# How to manipulate a single pixel on a buffer

Tags: c++, 3d, buffer, render, pixel

I am going to make a simple program that renders lines in 3D space with C++. I'm going to use bresenhams line algorithm and do all the math calculations from scratch. I need a way to get access too, and change pixels colors on a window of some sort. I've used SDL, Simple Direct Media layer to get access to its buffer and manipulate pixels, and I've also used Win32 API to change its window buffer to manipulate pixels.I was wondering if there is any other way, be it a library or api that is faster at doing this. Also, how would I go about making a simple window and buffer from scratch? Just point me in the right direction and I'll take it from there!

Comment: Have you used [`CreateDibSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183494.aspx)? It's about as close as Windows has to what you seem to want.

Comment: I messed around and got something working. If DIB stuff and buffer / bitmpa stuff in Win32 api is the way to go then I'm gonna look into it much more. thnx